# Checking interface connectivity from Bluemix platform

Tags: java, shell, ibm-cloud, remoting, connectivity

My Bluemix application is supposed to connect to a server / database outside the bluemix environment, i.e., it is not hosted by Bluemix but is in the local data centre.

Now I would like to check connectivity from Bluemix to the remote database. Is it possible to log into the "Bluemix workspace" and execute commands from there or would I need to install a utility app to test the connectivity?

Comment: The answer depends on the type of app you are running. Is it a Cloud Foundry app or something in a Docker container or in a VM (or even OpenWhisk)?

Comment: As a second comment: Are you using the Secure Gateway or similar software to tunnel into your data center? The data center should be protected and you should not be able to easily connect from any Internet environment into you local server.

Comment: Working on basic cloud foundry app written in java....No container or VM.. Simple web application pushed to blue mix..                                                       For second question, you are right it has to be secure channel to connect to our data centre. But the main issue I am having is writing basic utilities do these test, connections which can be easily done on linux/unix using command line. Do bluemix provide the shell to execute ping like command or do i have to wrap all utilities in java app to do small things

Comment: Bluemix Cloud Foundry apps typically are web applications. There are options to just have a service, no web interface. Some of my web apps have a special test/debug mode to check connectivity is up etc.